# how to disable di.xml virtual types from vendor in custom module

Tags: magento2.3.4, di.xml, virtualtype

I am currently experiencing an issue where a vendor module is using MSI, however we needed to disable it via composer completly ( magento 2.3.4 )
The vendor module in question is the amasty layered navigation module ( amasty/shopby) which in the di.xml has the following declarations:

````
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="defaultStockProvider" type="Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\Di\Wrapper">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Api\DefaultStockProviderInterface</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="stockIndexTableNameResolver" type="Amasty\ShopbyBase\Model\Di\Wrapper">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\StockIndexTableNameResolverInterface</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="stockResolver" xsi:type="object">stockResolver</argument>
            <argument name="defaultStockProvider" xsi:type="object">defaultStockProvider</argument>
            <argument name="stockIndexTableNameResolver" xsi:type="object">stockIndexTableNameResolver</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>```

Instead of commenting them out on the ```vendor/amasty/shopby/di.xml``` how is it possible to override that in a custom module and disable them ?
````

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question.

Today we've released a new version for Improved Layered Navigation for M2, where the following issue has been fixed.

Would you please upgrade the extension to 2.14.7 version and check if it works correctly for you?

In case of any struggles feel free to contact our support team at support@amasty.com, we'll be glad to assist you.

Kind regards,
Amasty Team